# emacs list of available functions in class for C++

Tags: c++, emacs24

I wanted to get complete list of function available for given class in C++ source code.

I am using CEDET with following configurations.

```
;; CEDET config
(semantic-mode 1)
;; Semantic
(global-semantic-idle-completions-mode t)
(global-semantic-decoration-mode t)
(global-semantic-highlight-func-mode t)
(global-semantic-show-unmatched-syntax-mode t)

;; CC-mode and C-mode hook
(defun my-ac-hook ()
(add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic)
(local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(linum-mode t))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-ac-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-ac-hook)
```

But I am not getting the list as expected. Is there anything I am missing in the configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic because this is about bad software, not bad programming style.

Comment: @dr_andonuts: Please clarify which software is bad and why you think it is bad.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews CEDET.  Whenever I've used it, it never works.  User: Have you tried using another tool for code completion, like http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete?

Comment: @dr_andonuts I did try AutoComplete but it did not work either.

Comment: This is now working. What I was missing in above setup is the project type. Found the solution at http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html